# Comparing two dataset, show number of total rows, if different show subjectids

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two datasets, where in the column `edta_complete` 0 is incomplete and 1 is complete. I am trying to compare these columns in df and df1. 1)I need to compare the counts of subject_ids with complete edta in both datasets. 2) If one dataset has more complete entries than another then show the subject_ids which differ. Please see e.g. below:

df:

```
df <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-2365"), edta_complete = c("1","0","1","1","1","0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c (NA, -6L))
```

df1:

```
df1 <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-2365"), edta_complete = c("1","1","1","1","1","1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c (NA, -6L))
```

Counts of edta_complete = 1

```
df %>% filter(edta_complete == 1) %>% nrow()
[1] 4
```

```
df1 %>% filter(edta_complete == 1) %>% nrow()
[1] 6
```

I need a code which will show me that in df1 `191-6784` and `191-2365` differ from df.
Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to find the subject_id that are found in df1 and not in df

```
setdiff(with(df1, subject_id[edta_complete == 1]), 
      with(df, subject_id[edta_complete == 1]))
[1] "191-6784" "191-2365"
```

---

Or use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  filter(edta_complete == 1) %>% 
  anti_join(df %>%
      filter(edta_complete == 1), by = 'subject_id') %>% 
  pull(subject_id)
[1] "191-6784" "191-2365"
```

Comment: Akrun, with the ```setdiff``` option, is it possible to have an output which shows the subject_id as well as their corresponding edta_complete values for each dataset so that it's easily comparable?

Comment: @Thandi You may use `%in%` with `!`, i.e. `df1[!with(df1, subject_id[edta_complete == 1]) %in%
      with(df, subject_id[edta_complete == 1]),]`

Comment: Akrun, previously I used the ```setdiff``` code but now realise the ```%in%``` method is better. However, when using this method I noticed that sometimes it returns subject ID's where both columns are the same, whereas I need it to show the subject ids where edta complete is 1 in df and 0 or NA in df1 and vice versa. Do you mind please explaining this code in words, and how I can modify when it's returning incorrect results? I used the same code as is on a different dataset with the same structure as the example above.

Comment: @Thandi `setdiff` is a set function which is applicable when you working on unique elements where as `%in%` with `!` works both in duplicate as welll as unique elements

Answer (score 1):

And also this using `bind_cols()`:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(df, df1) %>% 
  filter(edta_complete...2 != edta_complete...4) %>% 
  pull(subject_id...1)
```

```
[1] "191-6784" "191-2365"
```